# Spring Boot : Consuming Apache cxf SOAP service with basic auth

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, basic-authentication, consumer

I am setting up SOAP service, using Apache cxf and spring boot, with basic auth. I am trying to consume this service but I have no idea how to pass username and password.

Here's my consumer:

```
public class Consumer {

    private Service service;
    public Consumer() throws MalformedURLException {
        URL wsdlURL = new URL("http://localhost:8081/soap/booksService?wsdl");
        QName SERVICE_NAME = new QName("http://service_interface.san.com/", "LibraryImplService");
        service = Service.create(wsdlURL,SERVICE_NAME);
    }
}
```

Here's service's security config:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("admin1").roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/soap/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

I have seen a lot of solutions with `BindingProvider` but I can't seem to get them working because I can't init `service = Service.create(wsdlURL,SERVICE_NAME);` due to auth issues.